# Java - Ramanujan Series for pi

Tags: java, math, pi

For one of my programs in my Computer Science class I have to calculate the value of pi using the following formula, I'm having trouble with the math equation in java.

Here's the math formula:
[Formula for 1/pi](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fpi+%3D%28%282%2asqrt%282%29%29%2F9801%29+sum_%28k%3D0%29%5Einfinity+%28%28%284k%29%21%2a%281103%2B%2826390%2ak%29%29%29%2F%28%28%28k%21%29%5E4%29%2a%28396%29%5E%284%2ak%29%29%29)

the formulas I used were:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
{
   term = ((calculate(4*i)*(1103+(26390*i)))/(Math.pow(calculate(i), 4))*Math.pow(396, (4*i)));
   sum += term;
}
sum *= ((2*Math.sqrt(2))/9801);
sum = Math.pow(sum, -1);
```

The for loop should calculate the sigma sign and everything to the right of it.
The next part should multiply that number by 2 square roots of 2 divided by 9801 and the final part should take that number to the -1st power, since the equation finds 1/pi this should reciprocate the fraction.

the calculate method just finds the factorial of a number.

When I run the program, the final answer is exactly pi at 1, 2.1355575437204093E-13 at 2, and it keeps printing wrong numbers. Any idea why this could be giving the wrong answer?

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: And your question is... And btw, why name it `calculate` when `factorial` is way more clear?

Comment: What is your problem? And btw, your formula for `term=` seems to be wrong, i'd assume you should use i, not k, in it.

Comment: That's what my professor wants it to be called, and I'll update the question so that it actually asks something in a second @m0skit0

Comment: I changed all the k's to i's and it didn't change the final answer. @GuntramBlohm

Comment: `long` is an integral type, so you should rather use `double` for your calculations.

Comment: Why would you cast `(2*Math.sqrt(2))/9801` to `long`, when it's clearly not a whole number?

Comment: Everything is now a double and I updated the question @GyroGearless

Comment: No, `double` isn't right either.  Those factorials will overflow the `double` data type before too long.

Comment: Maybe yous `Math.PI` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had your brackets wrong for your denominator:

```
term = (double)(calculate(4*i)*(1103+(26390*i)))/((Math.pow(calculate(i), 4))*Math.pow(396, (4*i)));
```

Try using doubles for your calculations. And with a value of k = 30, the result is `3.141592653589793`

And determining the value of PI is like applying stochastics to find a deterministic value, using large iterations gives a better precision

Comment: if the ans is true there should be +1 na. ?? :D so +1 from me. :D