# How would I enter the Ramanujan series formula into java?

Tags: java

here is the formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation

How would Enter this into java?

Im trying to calculate PI using this formula.

Comment: In java, you can use + for summation, - for subtracting, * for multiplication, / for dividing... I hope that helped, good luck with your homework!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it (1) lacks information regarding the problem encountered, (2) is too broad because the OP doesn't seem to know basics of programming, (3) lacks any research effort (there would be numerous examples for the problem already).

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar topic already on stack overflow, hope it helps:

[Java - Ramanujan Series for pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600878/java-ramanujan-series-for-pi)